# visual VM with JDK problem

Tags: java, jdk

I'm new to ubuntu ,i'm trying to use tool called jvisualvm to know if there is amemory leak or not , i got after after installed it 
[image]

```
update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
 * 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java          1062      manual mode
 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error was in the configuration file in program itself so it could't read right version i want

Answer (score 0):

You don't have JDK installed; you have JRE (although I suspect you already know that). To get that application to work, you need to install OpenJDK:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

That should set itself to the default Java version, but if it doesn't, you can run the command you have in your question to make it the default.

Comment: i installed it already but it didn't appear under this command update-alternatives --config java

Comment: That maybe should have been made clear __;-)__. As your question stands, it sounds like you just don't have JDK installed.

Comment: Try rebooting and see where that gets you.

Comment: i rebooted machine and same result i tried to install it again and got eading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-6-jdk is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libck-connector0 openvswitch-common openvswitch-pki ssh-import-id
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 339 not upgraded.

Comment: Install JDK 7, not 6

Comment: error was in the configuration file in program itself so it could't read right version i want , Thanks for your time